# System showing alert after plugging in headphones

Tags: 20.04, headphones

My system is showing a symbol after plugging headphones in. Whenever I play any song or video the symbol disappers until I stop the music. The sound quality is fine, so there is no problem with the headphones. This issue started last week, and I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed.

[image: Image of Error]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The picture is of the WiFi screen. I do not see the direct relation to this and your question.

Comment: The squared card containing symbol which the cyan colored arrow is pointing to, it is the problem. Whenever I connect headphones that symbol appears on screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try these commands:

   ```
   pulseaudio --kill
   pulseaudio --start
   sudo service acpid restart
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
   acpi_listen
   ```
3. Now unplug your headphones and plug them again as you can see below

   ```
   jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
   jack/microphone MICROPHONE unplug
   jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
   jack/microphone MICROPHONE plug
   ```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem still persists :(